# Add events dynamically to a div

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the following div:

```
<div id="mylist">
```

Inside this div, I have another div I want to dynamically create:

```
<div id="object3" class="objects" 
  draggable="true"
  ondragstart="drag_start(event)" 
  ondragend="drag_end(event)">
  BWA
</div>
```

Right now I wrote a function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  node.className="objects";
  node.draggable= "true";
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("BWA");
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(node);
}
```

How could I append `ondragstart="drag_start(event)"` and `ondragend=drag_end(event)"` dynamically to the div I create?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look for "mouseup" and "mousedown" events, perhaps.

Comment: Instead of inline ondragstart try using [`Element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with event name as `"dragstart"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```
node.addEventListener("dragstart", drag_start, false);
node.addEventListener("dragend", drag_end, false);
```

This assumes the `drag_start` and `drag_end` functions are declared in the correct scope and that the events will be fired by your element.

Comment: I notice that I could achieve the result by doing `event.target.appendChild(_(elem_id).cloneNode(true))` But thanks!